# "<identifier> expected" when creating class from template

Tags: java

I have a bot I am creating that can take input from an IRC channel to create new classes for the bot to use when running. However, when it tries to compile the class, it results in an "identifier expected" error at the class name. However, if I type up a class which is identical to that created by the bot using the template, it compiles without issue. Below are the 3 methods used for this process:

```
//Create basic command
public static int writeBasicCommand(String trigger, String output, boolean edit) {
    int success = 0, existenceError = 1, unknownError = 2;
    try {
        String filePath = "C:/commands/" + trigger + ".java"; //Location for new class
        File file = new File(filePath);

        //Check if command exists
        if (file.exists()) {
            if(!edit) {
                return existenceError;
            }
        } else if(edit) {
            return existenceError;
        }

        //Grab and modify template
        String template = readFile("C:/template.txt");
        String namedCom = template.replace("--COMMANDNAME--", trigger);
        String content = namedCom.replace("--COMMANDRESULT--", "\"" + output + "\"");

        //Write command
        WriteFile(content, file, false);
        if (Compile(filePath)==true) {
            System.out.println("Done");
            return success;
        } else {
            return unknownError;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return unknownError;
    }
}

//Compile new commands
public static boolean Compile(String fileToCompile) {
    System.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_11");
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
    if(compilationResult == 0) {
        System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
        if ((new File(fileToCompile).exists())) {
            new File(fileToCompile).delete();
        }
        return false;
    }
}

//Write to a file
public static boolean WriteFile(String fileContents, File destination, boolean append) {
    try {

        // if file doesnt exist, then create it
        if (!destination.exists()) {
            destination.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(destination.getAbsoluteFile(), append);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(fileContents);
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if one file compiles and the other doesn't, they're clearly not *identical*. I suggest you use a diff tool to find out what the difference is.

Comment: This looks scary.  Couldn't you do without code generation by using the *Command* pattern or something similar?

Comment: I don't have any clue what the difference could be. I have opened both in text editors side by side and saw no difference between them

Comment: @5gon12eder I looked up "Command pattern" but I'm not sure that would work in this situation. I would need to be able to save the class for use at a later time even after shutting down the bot.

Comment: It's hard to tell you a solution without really knowing what you want to accomplish.  Note however that you can easily persist any object (meaning *instance of class*, not *class*) to disk and re-load it later using the object serialization infrastructure that comes with Java.

Comment: @5gon12eder The objects in the bot usually don't last very long because of them being on a per-message basis. Therefore I want to write the .java file according to a template and compile it. I am also wanting to be able to edit it at any time

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you are trying to do can be done without compiling code on the fly but if you wish to discuss this, you should probably step back a bit and have a broader look at your problem.  Then (if necessary) maybe ask a new question where you explain your goal on an abstract level and we'll see if we can find a solution.  I don't think we can (or at least, shouldn't) discuss this in this comment section of a mostly unrelated question.